# Flex, removing event listeners and binding setter

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I've a big application with a complex UI (built in Flex 3.6). There are a lot of nested components, most of them  have event listeners or binding setters. The structure is something like:

```
- Client View
         - Portfolio View
         - Personal data
         - etc. etc.
- Manager view
         - etc. etc.
```

Sometime I've to destroy the client view to reinitialize it; what I do is to remove it from it's container; but it seems that the memory don't get correctly garbage collected (the problem is the presence of the event listeners and data bindings).

Reading books and forums I've found that the best way to manage this situation is to remove the data bindings and event listeners on object destruction. But how I can do that ? Who tells the last children of the Client View hierarchy that it has been removed ?

I've implemented it via "addedToStage" and "removedFromStage" event handlers - it seemed to work, but it's a sort of workaround; this event get called a lot of time and that slow down the rendering.

**So my question is: this problem I think is common, there is a better solution ?**

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that disposing and re-activating the component based on their appearance on the stage is a workaround? It is very common do it like this and personally I don't see any particular reason not to do this.

Although I'm working on mobile projects only, this is basically the exact same method I handle the deactivation and reactivation of components. Once removed from stage, all event handlers get removed and added again as soon as the component gets added again. 
Other than that, I've got an additional method that completely disposes the component, so first removes event listeners, deletes any references to the object and finally nulls it.

Comment: The problem is that this events are fired a lot of times, above all if the components are inside a view stack. I found it strange that in every guide, manual, forum, etc. everybody tells to remove event listeners but nobody says when to do this. The fact that I'm not the only one who uses this solution make me happy.

Comment: When to remove an event listener is fairly simple, as soon as you don't need it any more. For example, the `AddedToStage` listener can be removed as soon the event has fired, just keep in mind to add it again in case you want to use the object again, that way the event will fire only once, just as it should.

Comment: The problem is that it calls addtostage and removefrom stage so I can't remove the add to stage event. I found that this kind of behavior happens when a display object is removed from it's father and put into a variable (this happens in view stack manipulation). But if this is the common way of working, I've just to rethink what we do in the binding setters.

Comment: What do you mean you can't remove the addedToStage listener? You've got a component X that has an `addedToStage` listener that fires, say, `addedToStageHandler()`. In that event handler, simply remove the `addedToStageListener`. The same applies for the `removedFromStage` listener. Remove it in the handler and add the `addedToStage` handler again in case you need it.

Comment: If flex call removefromstage and after call the addtostage (it does it on view stack and other cases) but I've removed it I remain without listeners.